# Is the modulus number uniquely determined when given multiplicative inverse elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the multiplicative group of integers modulo a prime $p$. Suppose that I don't know $p$ but, for some $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$ I know the multiplicative inverse elements $x^{-1}$ and $y^{-1}$ modulo $p$. Does this uniquely define $p$, if we assume that $p>x$ and $p>y$?

I've tried the following but I'm stuck: Suppose there are $p$ and $p'$ such that If $x x^{-1} = 1\ (mod\ p)$ and $x x^{-1} = 1\ (mod\ p')$.
It follows that there are integers $k\ne k'>0$ such that
$$
k p = k' p'.
$$
This is satisfied if $k'=p$ and $k=p'$. But how does the second assumption (about $y$ and it's inverse) come into play?

Comment: We could let $x=1$ and $y=-1$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that $x, y >1$.

Answer (score 1):

if you want $p>x^{-1}$we have $pp'|xx^{-1}-1\to xx^{-1}>pp'+1$but $xx^{-1}<p$ it is impossible so x and $x^{-1}$ determined p.if you have not this condition (4,14)and(2,28) mod 5,11 is a counterexample

Comment: Why does $p p' \mid x x^{-1} -1$ hold?

Comment: it is clear.because p and p' divide $xx^{-1}-1$

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

If you know the inverses of $x,y$ you know that $p|xx^{-1}-1$ and $p|yy^{-1}-1$.

Therefore 
$$p| gcd (xx^{-1}-1, yy^{-1}-1)$$

As long as $gcd (xx^{-1}-1, yy^{-1}-1)$ is a power of a prime, $p$ is determined uniquely, otherwise all the primes dividing the gcd work.

For example, pick some $n$ which is not a power of prime, so that $n+1$ also has at least three divisors. It is very easy to find such numbers, and you can prove that there are infinitely many such $n$'s. Then you can find two distinct pairs $(x,a), (y,b)$ such that 
$$xa=n+1$$
$$yb=n+1$$
If $p,q$ are two distinct primes dividing $n$ then $a=x^{-1}, b=y^{-1}$ both modulo $p$ and modulo $q$.

**Added** If you want $x,y <p,q$ the best strategy is to pick $p,q \geq 3$ to be two primes close to eachother, $n=pq$, such that $n+1$ is not twice a prime. Then $x=2$ and $y=$ the second smallest divisor of $n+1$ works most of the time.

For example, when $p=5, q=7$ we get that the inverse of $2$ is $18$ mod $5,7$ and the inverse of $4$ is $9$ mod $5,7$.

If you want the solution to be unique, you probably also need the condition $x^{-1}, y^{-1} <p$.

Comment: But it seems we also want $p>x,y>1$ so $n$ needs at least two different odd prime factors.  I believe $n=104$ meets your criteria but not the OP's.

Comment: @N.S: If $x^{-1}$ and $y^{-1}$ are also both $<p$, why would $p$ become unique?

Answer (score 0):

In $Z_8$, the inverses of $5$ and $7$ are (respectively) $5$ and $7$. This also happens in $Z_{12}$.

Comment: Unless you desired $p$ to be prime, but you hadn't mentioned that.

Comment: Sorry, yes $p$ should be prime. I'm editing the question... :(